# Installing Jupyter extensions from SageMath under Docker with Windows10

Tags: jupyter-notebook

My question is certainly naive but I do not understand many aspects of the installation of SageMath under Docker with windows 10.

I have a functional Sagemath container under docker. I know that from Jupyter one can call pip... So I try

> pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions && jupyter contrib
> nbextension install

All seems fine until I receive the message

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter'
```

I know that this is certainly a problem of rights. But I don't know what to do. Reading https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/howto/admin/enable-extensions.html, I see some Linux commands as

> sudo

I need a little help. Thanks